# How to set a subform to null when it's not submitted?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

## Short Version

- The form data is: `['model' => new TestModel(123)]`
- The form gets submitted with the following data: `[]`
- What I expect: `['model' => null]`
- What I get: `['model' => $anEmptyInstanceOfTestModel]`

## Long Version

I have a simple form. This form has a subform (key "model") for my custom FormType.

If I initialize the form with data where "model" already present, the model won't be null, even if **no data** for model **was submitted**. On the other hand, if the init data has null for "model", the value of "model" stays null.

## Question

*How do I configure my form to set "model" to null if nothing was submitted?*

I already tried setting `'required' => false` and / or `'empty_data' => null` which both doesn't seem to help.

## Minimalistic example as unit test

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Common\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class NullModelTest extends TypeTestCase {

    public function testNullOnNotSubmitted() {
        $tm = new TestModel(123);
        $data = ['model' => $tm];
        $form = $this->factory->createBuilder(FormType::class, $data)
                ->add('model', TestModelType::class, ['required' => false])
                ->getForm();
        $form->submit([]); // submit no data
        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertNull($form->getData()['model']); // ERROR: returns the empty model
    }

}

class TestModel {
    protected $id;
    public function __construct($id = null) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function setId($id) { $this->id = $id; }
}

class TestModelType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('id', TextType::class);
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefault('data_class', TestModel::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this is a very rare scenario. In "real" HTML forms there is no such thing like "it's not submitted at all". IMO this is the reason that a feature like setting the sub-form to `null` doesn't exist. Furthermore: sub-forms may only represent a slice of the real model. Imagine the sub-form only handles the field "name" of a customer. The customer itself has many fields. In classic HTML forms this sub-form would render as a simple text field. Now imagine your whole customer will be set to `null` after not submitting anything for this sub-form. Seems pretty wrong ;) The option `empty_data` is for initializing an non-initialized object (e.g. your customer) before populating data - not for replacing it, if it already exists.

I reached this type of scenario because I use the Symfony Forms to populate my models with request data in a secure and structured way. Therefore my request data is pretty much custom (JSON API) and whole sub-forms can be null or not even there.

At the moment I used the following EventSubscriber to dynamically

1. look if the request data is null and store this for a later replacement of data
2. replace the data at a later point (because I need to replace the norm data, not the request data [which is already `null`])

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Replaces the data of this form type by the given value if it's not part of the request data.
 */
class ReplaceIfNotSubmittedListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'preSubmit',
            FormEvents::SUBMIT => 'submit',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $shouldBeReplaced = false;

    /**
     * @var mixed|callable
     */
    private $replaceValue;

    public function __construct($replaceValue) {
        $this->replaceValue = $replaceValue;
    }

    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        if ($event->getData() === null) {
            $this->shouldBeReplaced = true;
        }
    }

    function submit(FormEvent $event) {
        if ($this->shouldBeReplaced) {
            $value = $this->replaceValue;
            $event->setData(is_callable($value) ? $value() : $value);
        }
    }

}
```

... and the usage in the modified main form:

```
$fb = $this->factory->createBuilder(FormType::class, $data);
$model = $this->factory->createBuilder()
            ->create('model', TestModelType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->addEventSubscriber(new ReplaceIfNotSubmittedListener(null));
$fb->add($model);
$form = $fb->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is bug, because this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/use_empty_data.html#option-2-provide-a-closure says you could have closure (that could return NULL), but it didnt work for me either.

Very simple solution is though using DataTransformer:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class NullToEmptyTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {
    public function transform($object) {
        return $object;  //DO NOTHING
    }
    public function reverseTransform($object) {
        if (is_null($object->getId()))
            return NULL; //Return NULL if object is empty
        return $object;
    }
}
```

and attaching this to your form field:

```
$fb = $this->factory->createBuilder(FormType::class, $data);
$model = $this->factory->createBuilder()
            ->create('model', TestModelType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->addModelTransformer(new NullToEmptyTransformer());
$fb->add($model);
$form = $fb->getForm();
```

Comment: The problem here is: model transformers transform norm-data to model-data. The norm-data for a compound form in this case is already the model object. The `null` is only in request data, which can only be addressed by events.

I did a workaround at the moment  workaround using an event subscriber. I subscribe to PRE_SUBMIT and SUBMIT. If I see `null` in PRE_SUBMIT (request-data), i store this. In SUBMIT I check if I saw a `null` before and if so, I reset the data. This works but should be used with caution, because it causes strange behavior in e.g. CollectionType entries.